# Magento - Can I package extension using localhost magento setup?

Tags: php, magento

I have build the module on my local magento setup (localhost) and now I want to create the package extension for the same.

I added the package configration in my local magento admin and created the extension key successfully. my machine Is connected with internet as well so Is is possible to use localhost magento setup to package the magento extension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can..There is no problem packaging module in local server.Just follow the packaging instruction..

Follow this link for perfect packing

***[Click me](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension_in_1.5)***